# mysql thread not executing. Still in sleep state

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I was running benchmark test in mysql server using mysqlslap. But sometimes the last thread in the pool is not executing and closing the connection. It keeps in sleep state.

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+-----+------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id  | User | Host                  | db        | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+-----+------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
|   2 | root | 122.178.231.xxx:15832 | mysqlslap | Sleep   |  740 |       | NULL                  |
| 106 | root | localhost             | NULL      | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show full processlist |
+-----+------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea? It happens often :(

This was the command I executed.

> mysqlslap -h IP_address -u root --auto-generate-sql  --concurrency=100
>   -pPASSWORD -vvv --number-of-queries=2500

my.cnf file is as follows,

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
skip-bdb
max_connections = 500
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 64M
key_buffer_size = 425M
query_cache_limit = 1024M
thread_cache_size = 4M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1360M
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
long_query_time = 5
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 300
max_allowed_packet = 128M

net_read_timeout = 240
net_write_timeout = 240
table_lock_wait_timeout =240
connect_timeout = 30

log-warnings = 2
log = /var/log/mysqld.log
log-error = /var/log/mysqld.error.log
log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysql_slow_queries.log
```

Comment: why is people clicking -1 button? I dont know whether this is a fooling question. Mysql was crashing often and I'm changing the parameters googling and running again. please help

Comment: Also check out http://blog.dbadojo.com/2008/02/mysql-vs-mysqlslap-round-3.html